# combine two arrays into a third array

Tags: php

I have two array

```
$arr1 = array(
    'setting_one' => 'abc',
    'setting_two' => 'def',
    'setting_three' => 'test'
);

$arr2 = array(
    'setting_two' => 'user defined'
);

$arr3= array();
```

I want `$array3` to look like

```
array(
    'setting_one' => 'abc';
    'setting_two' => 'user defined',
    'setting_three' => 'test'
);
```

how can i merge two arrays into a third array? Take into a real world example that the first two arrays are settings arrays, the first array is a global array while the second array is user defined settings. The third array is a combination of the two array while favoring the second array values over the global settings arrays.

Comment: Is there any reason you cant just overwrite the value? instead of making $arr2

Comment: @LawrenceCherone There might be a longer list of custom settings?

Comment: @ChasingDeath Ya, array 2 may have more settings not provided by the global settings arrays.

Comment: So ya have a reason to use array_merge ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arr3 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

This merges arr2 into arr1 (meaning any collision is resolved by using the value from arr2).

Note that this is not recursive and will not merge sub arrays in the manner that you probably expect.

http://php.net/array_merge

Comment: Oh hmmm, i took a look at this prior to posting but needed to make sure. And I understad that recursive isn't a feature. thanks for clearing it up

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr3 = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

array_merge() does the overriding from the second array for you.